# Reading when write is restricted on Mifare Ultralight C

Tags: android, authentication, nfc, rfid, mifare

I have just received Mifare Ultralight C. I can easily read values from it using android phone(Galaxy Ace 3).

```
0 hex: 04 9a 6f 79
1 hex: 52 02 3a 80
2 hex: ea 48 00 00
3 hex: 00 00 00 00
4 hex: 02 00 00 10
5 hex: 00 06 01 10
6 hex: 11 ff 00 00
7 hex: 00 00 00 00
8 hex: 00 00 00 00
9 hex: 00 00 00 00
10 hex: 00 00 00 00
11 hex: 00 00 00 00
12 hex: 00 00 00 00
13 hex: 00 00 00 00
14 hex: 00 00 00 00
15 hex: 00 00 00 00
16 hex: 00 00 00 00
17 hex: 00 00 00 00
18 hex: 00 00 00 00
19 hex: 00 00 00 00
20 hex: 00 00 00 00
21 hex: 00 00 00 00
22 hex: 00 00 00 00
23 hex: 00 00 00 00
24 hex: 00 00 00 00
25 hex: 00 00 00 00
26 hex: 00 00 00 00
27 hex: 00 00 00 00
28 hex: 00 00 00 00
29 hex: 00 00 00 00
30 hex: 00 00 00 00
31 hex: 00 00 00 00
32 hex: 00 00 00 00
33 hex: 00 00 00 00
34 hex: 00 00 00 00
35 hex: 00 00 00 00
36 hex: 00 00 00 00
37 hex: 00 00 00 00
38 hex: 00 00 00 00
39 hex: 00 00 00 00
40 hex: 00 00 00 00
41 hex: 00 00 00 00
42 hex: 30 00 00 00
43 hex: 00 00 00 00
```

Then I'm changing values in page 43 to `0x80` and page 42 to `0x2A`. Now when I'm reading values this way:

```
Log.e(LOG, "read");
for(int j = 0; j <= 40; j += 4){
byte[] resp = mifare.readPages(j);
logResponse(j, resp);


private void logResponse(int j, byte[] resp){
     for(int i = 0; i < resp.length; i += 4){
            Log.e(LOG, String.valueOf(j + i / 4) + " hex: " 
                    + String.format("%02x ", resp[i])
                    + String.format("%02x ", resp[i + 1]) 
                    + String.format("%02x ", resp[i + 2]) 
                    + String.format("%02x", resp[i + 3]));
      }
}
```

I'm getting values from page 0 and 1 instead of 42 and 43.
Next thing is that when I send message `0x1A00` in order to authenticate, I'm getting `transceive failed`. 
Is there a way to check if it actually is Mifare Ultralight C or some other tag? Or am I wrong that value `0x80` in page 43 only restricts write access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content that you read from the tag does look as if it could be a MIFARE Ultralight C tag (particularly that you were able to read pages 42 and 43).

- The roll-over that you see after setting AUTH0 to 42 (0x2A) is expected behavior. I.e. when you protect the tag memory starting at page X, the READ command will roll-over after page X - 1.
- Setting AUTH1 to 0x80 will not do what you expected. Only the lowest bit in AUTH1 is relevant, so you would typically set AUTH1 to either 0x00 (restrict read and write) or 0x01 (restrict only write).
- I'm not quite sure why the authentication command fails though.

  ```
  byte[] cmd = { (byte)0x1A, (byte)0x00 };
  byte[] result = mifare.transceive(cmd);
  ```

  Typically, if this command returns anything other that 0xAF (or throws an exception), that is a clear indication that a tag is *not* MIFARE Ultralight C.

Comment: Just tested AUTH1 values and you are right about it, my mistake. It is really weird that it restricts reading/writing correctly but has problems with authentication command. To be clear, I'm using MifareUltralight as mifare object, is it ok?

Comment: Both MifareUltralight and NfcA are okay. YOu are sending the zero byte after the 0x1A byte, right? Also what operations do you use *before* sending the authentication command? Are you performing any read/write operations?

Comment: My command is exactly the same as in your post. Only connect() before this command. I have already tried also with read before auth command, same behavior.

Comment: Could you try to read the tag with NFC TagInfo (mine or the one from NXP, should not matter) and check what it reports as the tag type?

Comment: That's really strange. Are you sure that those are genuine tags manufactured by NXP? Usually for NXP's tags I would trust the result of NXP's TagInfo app more than mine. So it might actually be an NTAG203. Regarding the result of NFC TagInfo:

Comment: The algorithm I use to determine if it is NTAG203 or Ultralight C is as follows: Check if the tag has 44 readable pages (separate READ commands are issued to find the very last page / to determine the roll-over point). If that is the case, the tag is considered Ultralight C. Otherwise, the authentication command is issued. If it succeeds (i.e. 0xAF is received), the tag is considered Ultralight C, otherwise NTAG203.

Comment: I guess NXP TagInfo just checks for the authentication command and thus reports NTAG203. However, this tag definitely either allows the read command for pages 0 to 43 or supports the authentication command, which should both not be the case for NTAG203.

Comment: I don't think that this tag is made by NXP. Actually I have them from 2 different suppliers(1 from china) - both have the same behavior and with same default data on pages 4, 5 and 6(if u count from 0).

Comment: Then I guess you got some counterfeit product that simply does not support the Ultralight C authentication command. Btw. today's new release of NFC TagInfo (1.12a) will show a warning (in the Ultralight C "Memory information" section) if the authentication command is not supported on a tag that was detected as Ultralight C.